# Insulate pot lid

Tags: comfort, temperature

[image]Is there something I can add to the knob on my pot lid to insulate it from the heat so I can pick it up ?

I currently have to use a pot holder to check on my chile, etc.

Answer (score 5):

**HACK** a *POT-LID KNOB COZY*

If you have a single heavy sock from an evil washing machine that stole its mate, cut off the toe and slip it over the protruding knob. The knob will hold the sock toe cozy in place during your meal preparation.

No more dealing with the oversize separate pot holder.

Good luck

Comment: That's an idea as I have some single socks. I found this. https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0897TRY6V/ref=ppx_od_dt_b_asin_title_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 I should be able to glue it to the knob.

Comment: @fixit7 Remember that silicone needs to be glued with silicone, or a more typical glue that has a primer for silicone.

Comment: "evil washing machine that stole its mate" +1 for that alone. (But the answer itself did also rate that +1)  A tunnel with an elastic band at the cut end will allow you to take it off and put back on, and washing it separate from the lid.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of things I would try:

1) "Sugru" would probably make a nice finish but I don't know how well it would survive washing-up.

2) Silicone sealant is pretty cheap and would work well - but it will be quite tricky to apply it in a layer all over the knob

Comment: I only hand wash it. I may also buy a know like you use for a cabinet door.

Comment: Sugru survives **years** of daily dish-washer abuse. I actually use it to cover weak spots inside my dishwasher itself, covering areas where the plastic-covered metal baskets are starting to get exposed metal areas [yes, it's old, no I can't afford to replace it yet]. Silicone bath sealant is nowhere near as good.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for that information. I've only used it once myself and it wasn't in a harsh environment.

Answer (score 1):

Typically these glass lids are mounted with a single bolt through the glass to the knob. I'd unscrew that, remove the knob, and in its place mount a piece of wood with a reasonable shape to use for a knob. So, spherical or cylindrical would be good for a start.

To mount it, I'd pre-drill a small diameter hole and then use a stainless steel wood screw (spax screw; or technically a "cross recess countersunk head spaced thread screw"). Take care to use the original washer that was mounted on the inside, and take care to not create any force on the edges of the hole that goes through the glass – that could make the glass lid break.